# Cannot start cool-retro-term

Tags: xubuntu

.

Hello, guys.

I cannot start cool-retro-term emulator. Output from terminal is below:

```
cool-retro-term 
Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None 
of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based 
authentication failed
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
default KB_LAYOUT_DIR:  "/snap/cool-retro-term/32/usr/lib/x86_64- 
linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QMLTermWidget/kb-layouts"
QObject::connect: No such slot 
Konsole::TerminalDisplay_QML_135::close()
loadAllColorSchemes
Session::run() - program: "/bin/bash"
Session::run() - arguments: ("")
started!
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing draw buffer.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing draw buffer.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing draw buffer.
QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing attachment.
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
Fragment shader for simpleShaderProg (MainFragmentShader & 
ShockingPinkSrcFragmentShader) failed to compile
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
Fragment shader for blitShaderProg (MainFragmentShader & 
ImageSrcFragmentShader) failed to compile
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
Warning: "" failed to compile!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)



sudo cool-retro-term 
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Aborted
```

In case you have some ideas on how to solve the issue, please share them. It will be appreciated.

I use latest Xubuntu.

Comment: Please describe how do you installed cool-retro-term? And what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: dsstorefile1, starting the app by typing its name didn't work, so I tried sudo just in case. Though, I do not understand your question completely.

Comment: I installed retro term  via software manager that is preinstalled in xubuntu.
I use brand-new installation of Xubuntu. I downloaded ISO file a couple of days ago from Xubuntu's website and installed all updates afterwards. 
Here is screenfetch output:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
Uptime: 23m
DE: XFCE
WM: Xfwm4
WM Theme: Numix
GTK Theme: Numix [GTK2]
Icon Theme: Paper
CPU: Intel Core i7-2760QM @ 8x 3.5GHz [47.5°C]
GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
RAM: 1400MiB / 7882MiB

Comment: In software manager it is said that snap store was used as source

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed it using snap try refreshing with **devmode** and latest edge build.

```
sudo snap refresh cool-retro-term --devmode --edge
```

You can then run without sudo, that is

```
cool-retro-term
```

If you didn't install via snap, uninstall it manually, then install using snap:

```
sudo snap install  cool-retro-term --devmode --edge
```

Comment: I confirm that `sudo snap refresh cool-retro-term --devmode --edge` fixed the segmentation fault I got downloading _cool-retro-terminal_ from the snap store.  Thank you.